# How does the user session work for OAuth2 authentication type Jhipster application?

Tags: jhipster

An Oauth2 client application generated by Jhipster has a behaviour issue after some idle time. After a signed-in user has some idle time on the application, interaction with the application will lead to an undesired behavior such as a data isn't fetched from the database.

I have learned that user session data is stored in a form of a cookie on the front end. For the Vue front-end, searching

```
this.$cookie.set(
```

yields no result.

I do see JSESSIONID in a request header after a user signs into the application. So, I assume that the session id also is stored somewhere on the server. For every REST request, the server would verify the session id in the request header by comparing it with the session id on the server. When the session is time out, the server no longer has the session id. Any REST request from the point will lead to undesired behaviour in the current implementation. A filter is needed to verify a REST request session id with the server.

I have a look at the code in the security package as well as the security configuration. But, I don't see any code dealing with a user session.

How does the server work in this regard?

**Update:**

To deal with an invalid user session for a sign-in, I notice that the ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver will handle the InsufficientAuthenticationException after refreshing a browser. Otherwise, the exception won't be handled. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: JHipster's OAuth implementation does use the session. That's where access tokens and refresh tokens are stored. When that session times out, you have to log in again. This is more secure than storing them on the client, but does have the downside of not having a long-lived refresh token. JHipster can act as a resource server too and validate JWTs passed in. That's how it works with React Native and Ionic.

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks for the insight, Based on my experience, a JHipster app doesn't enforce a relog-in after the session time out. That creates a bad user experience for an unknown application interaction result. For example, I have a situation that data (from DB) is missing on a page after a click. If this user has "to log in again" in this case, the app should pop up a login screen or a panel with time-out and action message, or so on. We try to fix this user experience problem, but can't find the code to make proper changes.

Comment: @MattRaible Can you provide a suggestion on how to deal with InsufficientAuthenticationException, please?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it. Can you please enter an issue in the JHipster project with steps to reproduce?

Comment: I can open a ticket for the problem. We have opened quite a few tickets, but most of them are closed without doing anything about them, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples of ones that are closed? We usually only close ones that lack information, we can't reproduce, or where the reporter is unresponsive.

Comment: Administration Data Missing With OAuth Client Implementation (#16704) (this one shall be an easy fix by porting over related code from a non-OAuth app). Browser Language Preference Needs To Be Honored (#15744) (I fix this one on our app)